# Html elements in a dynamic form not updating properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring, forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic html form where the user can add and delete input boxes. These input boxes are appended by cloning and deleting a hidden 'clone div' to an empty div at the next available index. On deletion of a div, a re-index method triggers which should re-index each of the divs which are attached to the empty div.

Originally, I was using the following method to re-index the input within a loop: (which seems to work fine):

```
$(this).find('input').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionListIndex}].prompt`);
```

However, some divs contain multiple inputs so I started naming the individual inputs and updating each one separately in the following manner.

```
$(this).find('input[name="cloneChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionListIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceIndex}].choicePrompt`);
$(this).find('select[name="cloneValueChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionListIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceIndex}].choiceValue`);
```

This however seems to causing null values. The form itself looks correct i.e. text labels are being updated dynamically with the expected numbering, the issue seems to be on submitting the values. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Please see my code below for context:

```js
//---------------------- Append Clone Methods ---------------------------------------------------------//

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#cloneButton").click(function() {

    var originalDiv = $("#questionContainer");
    var questionCounter = originalDiv.find('.questionList').length;
    var clonedDiv = $("#cloneContainer").clone();


    var newId = "container" + (questionCounter);
    clonedDiv.attr("id", newId);

    var newClass = "questionList";
    clonedDiv.attr("class", newClass);

    var newLabel = "Question: " + (questionCounter + 1);
    clonedDiv.find("label").text(newLabel);

    clonedDiv.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    clonedDiv.find('input[name="questionPromptClone"]').attr('required', 'required');

    clonedDiv.find('input[name="questionPromptClone"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionCounter}].prompt`);
    clonedDiv.show();
    originalDiv.append(clonedDiv);
  });


  $(document).on("click", ".choiceButton", function() {
    var clonedChoiceDiv = $("#choiceTemplate").clone();

    var newClass = "choiceList";
    clonedChoiceDiv.attr("class", newClass);

    var questionDiv = $(this).closest('.questionList');
    var questionIndex = questionDiv.index();

    var choiceCounter = questionDiv.find('.choiceList').length;

    var choiceId = "choice" + choiceCounter;
    clonedChoiceDiv.attr("id", choiceId);

    var choiceLabel = "Choice: " + (choiceCounter + 1);
    clonedChoiceDiv.find("label").text(choiceLabel);

    clonedChoiceDiv.find('input[name="cloneChoice"]').attr('required', 'required');

    clonedChoiceDiv.find('input[name="cloneChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceCounter}].choicePrompt`);
    clonedChoiceDiv.find('select[name = "cloneValueChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceCounter}].choiceValue`);
    clonedChoiceDiv.show();
    questionDiv.append(clonedChoiceDiv);

  });



  $("#addMessageButton").click(function() {
    var originalDiv = $("#messageContainer");

    var messageCounter = originalDiv.find('.messageList').length
    if (messageCounter >= 6) {

      alert("The maximum number of message options is 6")
      return;
    }


    var clonedDiv = $("#cloneMessageContainer").clone();
    var newId = "messageContainer" + (messageCounter);
    clonedDiv.attr("id", newId);

    var newClass = "messageList";
    clonedDiv.attr("class", newClass);

    var newLabel = "Message: " + (messageCounter + 1);
    clonedDiv.find('label[name="cloneMessageText"]').text(newLabel);

    clonedDiv.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    clonedDiv.find('input[name="cloneMessageText"]').attr('required', 'required');
    clonedDiv.find('input[name="cloneMessageText"]').prop('name', `personalizedMessage[${messageCounter}].message`);
    clonedDiv.find('select[name="cloneMessageChoice"]').prop('name', `personalizedMessage[${messageCounter}].answerChoice`);
    clonedDiv.show();
    originalDiv.append(clonedDiv);
  });

  //------------------------------------------- Renumeber Index Methods ---------------------------------------------------------//


  function renumberQuestionChoices(questionDiv) {

    var choiceList = questionDiv.find('.choiceList');
    var questionIndex = questionDiv.index();
    choiceList.each(function(choiceIndex) {
      var newId = "choice" + (choiceIndex);
      $(this).attr("id", newId);

      var newLabel = "Choice: " + (choiceIndex + 1);
      $(this).find("label").text(newLabel);

      $(this).find('input[name="cloneChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceIndex}].choicePrompt`);
      $(this).find('select[name="cloneValueChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceIndex}].choiceValue`);

      alert(`Question Index: ${questionIndex}, Choice Index: ${choiceIndex}`);

    });
  }


  function renumberQuestionsAndChoices() {

    var originalDiv = $("#questionContainer");
    var questionList = originalDiv.find('.questionList');


    questionList.each(function(questionListIndex) {
      var newId = "container" + (questionListIndex);
      $(this).attr("id", newId);
      var newLabel = "Question: " + (questionListIndex + 1);
      $(this).find("label").text(newLabel);


      $(this).find('input[name="questionPromptClone"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionListIndex}].prompt`);

      $(this).find('.choiceList').each(function(choiceIndex) {
        var newId = "choice" + (choiceIndex);
        $(this).attr("id", newId);

        var newLabel = "Choice: " + (choiceIndex + 1);
        $(this).find("label").text(newLabel);

        $(this).find('input[name="cloneChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionListIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceIndex}].choicePrompt`);
        $(this).find('select[name="cloneValueChoice"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionListIndex}].questionChoice[${choiceIndex}].choiceValue`);
      });
    });
  }


  function renumberMessages() {
    var messageCounter = $(".messageList").length;

    if (messageCounter === 0) {
      return;
    }

    $(".messageList").each(function(index) {
      var newId = "message" + (index);
      $(this).attr("id", newId);

      var newLabel = "Message: " + (index + 1);
      $(this).find("label").text(newLabel);

      $(this).find('input[name = "cloneMessageText"]').prop('name', `personalizedMessage[${messageCounter}].message`);
      $(this).find('select[name = "cloneMessageChoice"]').prop('name', `personalizedMessage[${messageCounter}].answerChoice`);
    });
  }


  //----------------------------------------- Delete Methods ---------------------------------------------------------//


  $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    var questionDiv = $(this).closest('.questionList');
    questionDiv.find('.choiceList').remove();
    questionDiv.remove();
    renumberQuestionsAndChoices();
  });


  $(document).on("click", ".deleteMessageButton", function() {
    var messageDiv = $(this).closest('.messageList');
    messageDiv.remove();
    renumberMessages();
  });


  $(document).on("click", ".choiceDeleteButton", function() {
    var choiceDiv = $(this).closest('.choiceList');
    var questionDiv = $(this).closest('.questionList');
    choiceDiv.remove();
    renumberQuestionChoices(questionDiv);
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create Quiz</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form th:action="@{/api/v1/quiz/registerQuiz}" method="post" th:object=${quiz}>

    <div>
      <label> Title </label> <input type="text" th:field="*{quizTitle}" required/>
    </div>

    <!-- -------------   Container used for cloning/appending Questions  ------------------------------------>

    <div id="cloneContainer" style="display: none;" class="cloneClass">
      <label> Question: </label> <input type="text" name="questionPromptClone" />
      <button type="button" class="deleteButton">Delete Question</button>
      <button type="button" class="choiceButton">Add Choice</button>
    </div>

    <div id="questionContainer"></div>

    <div id="messageContainer"></div>


    <!-- -------------   Container used for cloning/appending Question Choices ------------------------------------>

    <div id="choiceTemplate" style="display: none;" class="cloneContainerClass">
      <label> Choice: </label> <input type="text" name="cloneChoice" />
      <label for="cloneValueChoice">Choice:</label>
      <select id="cloneValueChoice" name="cloneValueChoice">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" class="choiceDeleteButton">Delete Choice</button>
    </div>


    <!-- -------------   Container used for cloning/appending Messages  ------------------------------------>

    <div id="cloneMessageContainer" style="display: none;" class="cloneMessageClass">
      <label> Message: </label> <input type="text" style="width: 400px; height: 75px;" name="cloneMessageText" />
      <label for="cloneMessage">Corresponds to Choice: </label>
      <select id="cloneMessage" name="cloneMessageChoice">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" class="deleteMessageButton">Delete Message</button>
    </div>

    <div>

      <!-- Match the selector at the time when this code runs so it won't work for elements dynamically added to the DOM after the initial page load -->
      <button type="button" id="cloneButton">Add Question</button>
      <button type="button" id="addMessageButton">Add Message</button>

    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you submit the form, do you see the correct parameter names in the Network tab?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found my error- In my re-indexing method I was trying to update the 'name' attribute by attempting to use the .find() method on names that I had already changed in the 'append' methods i.e.

 clonedDiv.find('input[name="questionPromptClone"]').prop('name', `quizQuestion[${questionCounter}].prompt`);
   
Instead, I should have used the following code to differentiate/ update attribute fields within the same div, without overwriting one:
clonedDiv.find('input').prop 
clonedDiv.find('select').prop